# geometry installation error

Tags: ros, geometry

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hii, I am getting an error when I try to install geometry. Can somebody help me out. I tried installing geometry_msgs but its still showing me the same error. Can somebody help me with this.

Package geometry_msgs was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `geometry_msgs.pc' to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable No package 'geometry_msgs' found [rospack] warning: got non-zero exit status from executing backquote expression "ret="`PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/home/ascc/ros_workspace/geometry_msgs/../../lib/pkgconfig pkg-config --cflags geometry_msgs`" && echo $ret" in [/home/ascc/ros_workspace/geometry_msgs/manifest.xml]
[rospack] error in backquote expansion for tf

Thank you,
Regards,
Faizan Shaik

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12878/geometry-installation-error/) by [evolutionsdisaster](https://answers.ros.org/users/1196/evolutionsdisaster/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2012-02-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [evolutionsdisaster](https://answers.ros.org/users/1196/evolutionsdisaster/) on 2012-02-03**:\

I am using this as the source to download the package : http://ros.org/wiki/geometry Downloading it into my ros_workspace path.

1. Installing dependencies : rosdep install geometry. 2) Making the file : rosmake geometry.

Regards, Faizan Shaik

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-02-03**:
Please explain how you're trying to install these packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rosdep install only installs the system dependencies.  You will also need to make sure that all ROS dependencies of geometry are in your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH.  For example geometry_msgs are in common_msgs which appears to be what you compile is complaining about.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-02-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [evolutionsdisaster](https://answers.ros.org/users/1196/evolutionsdisaster/) on 2012-02-03**:
When I do rosmake geometry_msgs, though its able to build, its showing as no make files found. and yet its building. I am kind of skeptic on this part.

**Comment by [evolutionsdisaster](https://answers.ros.org/users/1196/evolutionsdisaster/) on 2012-02-03**:
Yes, you are right, but I have done rosmake geometry_msgs and also rosmake common_msgs. I did rosmake geometry_msgs separetely as well when I was getting that error. But still unable to figure out the problem.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-02-24**:
If there's no makefiles found then I expect you're trying to compile an installed version not a source checkout.  If you'd like more information please tell how your environment was created.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like you may be using the head branch of geometry; note that large parts of ROS are currently in flux and are possibly broken due to the upcoming Fuerte release.

If you don't need head, I suggest you either install from binaries if they're available for your system, or with a versioned rosinstall file.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2012-02-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [evolutionsdisaster](https://answers.ros.org/users/1196/evolutionsdisaster/) on 2012-02-04**:
I guess you are the author of it, can you have a look at it once, if its possible. I checked with the CMakeLists.txt file of geometry_msgs , I felt something is missing and also the error for many packages is pointing towards geometry_msgs. Can u please help me out.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-02-03**:
Very true, the trunk of any stack does not have any guarantees to work with anything in particular.   If you are checking out from source it is highly recommended to use a tag unless you are seeking to join the development effort of the stack.  If you do want to, I suggest you contact the maintainer